# Removing unnecessary sets of a refinement in a paracompact topological space.

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\mathcal T)$ be a [paracompact](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParacompactSpace.html) topological space and $\mathcal W$ be an open cover for $X$. Is there an open refinement $\mathcal U$ for $\mathcal W$, such that

$$\{U\in \mathcal U\mid (\forall V\in \mathcal U)(U\not\subset V)  \}$$
is a cover for $X$?

$\not\subset$ means "not **proper** subset".

> **Edit:**
>
> $\{U\in \mathcal U\mid (\forall V\in \mathcal U)(U\not\subset V)  \}$ 
>   must be an open cover in which all sets are maximal.

Comment: Try \not\subset

Comment: @ErickWong thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s true even if $X$ is only metacompact, meaning that every open cover has a point-finite open refinement. This follows from the following theorem, but first a definition: a family $\mathscr{F}$ of sets is *irreducible* if $F\nsubseteq\bigcup\left(\mathscr{F}\setminus\{F\}\right)$ for each $F\in\mathscr{F}$.

> **Theorem.** Let $\mathscr{U}$ be a point-finite open cover of a space $X$. Then $\mathscr{U}$ has an irreducible subcover.
>
> **Proof.** For each $x\in X$ let $\mathscr{U}(x)=\{U\in\mathscr{U}:x\in U\}$; this set is finite, so it has an irreducible subset $\mathscr{V}(x)$. Let $V(x)=\bigcup\mathscr{V}(x)$. Say that a set $D\subseteq X$ is $\mathscr{V}$-*discrete* if $V(x)\cap D=\{x\}$ for each $x\in D$. Let $$\mathfrak{D}=\{D\subseteq X:D\text{ is }\mathscr{V}\text{-discrete}\}\;;$$ then $\langle\mathfrak{D},\subseteq\rangle$ is a partial order. Let $\mathfrak C$ be a chain in this partial order, and let $D=\bigcup\mathfrak C$. If $x,y\in D$ with $x\ne y$, there is a $C\in\mathfrak C$ such that $x,y\in C$, so $y\notin V(x))$, and $D$ is $\mathscr{V}$-discrete. Thus, every chain in $\mathfrak D$ has an upper bound in $\mathfrak D$, and by Zorn’s lemma $\mathfrak D$ has a maximal element $D$.
> Let $\mathscr{V}=\bigcup_{x\in D}\mathscr{V}(x)$; then $\mathscr{V}$ is an irreducible subcover of $\mathscr{U}$. $\dashv$

Comment: thanks. I was waiting for your answer!

Comment: @CutieKrait: :-) You’re welcome!